# how to generate barcode in python 3.7

Tags: python, pip, barcode

I am using python 3.7, for barcode generation I am trying to install pyBarcode library using `pip install pyBarcode`'. but it shows the following error:

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyBarcode (from versions: )
no matching distribution found for pyBarcode

Now, how can I install `pyBarcode` for my Python version?

Answer (score 8):

1st install the right lib:

```
pip install python-barcode
```

then code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import barcode
from barcode.writer import ImageWriter

def testEan():
    EAN = barcode.get_barcode_class('ean13')
    ean = EAN(u'123456789011', writer=ImageWriter())
    fullname = ean.save('my_ean13_barcode')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    testEan()
```

this code produces

[image]

Comment: it also shows the following: no module named 'barcode.writer'; 'barcode' is not a package

Comment: please reply i need solution.

Comment: what version of python are you using? because this is working fine in my pc

Comment: Thank you for your answer . I found the solution and now, it's working properly.

Comment: note EAN13 is accept only numbers with limit for example it can not be 1234, also to add letters use Code128 instead of EAN13, from barcode import Code128

Answer (score 3):

## UPDATE

That means it does not support python 3.7.
Try this `pip install python-barcode`

Run this example to help you understand:

```
import barcode
from barcode.writer import ImageWriter
from barcode import generate

print(barcode.PROVIDED_BARCODES)
EAN = barcode.get_barcode_class('ean13')
ean = EAN('5901234123457')
fullname = ean.save('ean13_barcode')
ean = EAN('5901234123457', writer=ImageWriter())

f = open('barcode.svg', 'wb')
ean.write(f)

name = generate('EAN13', '5901234123457', output='barcode_svg')
generate('EAN13', '5901234123457', writer=ImageWriter(), output='barcode')
```

Comment: I tried that but i can't get 'barcode.PROVIDED_BARCODES' from that.

Comment: this code shows :  No module named 'barcode.writer'; 'barcode' is not a package

Comment: Did you run `pip install python-barcode` first? The error means you have not installed the package.

Comment: yes, I run pip install python-barcode. It shows requirement already satisfied.

Comment: Then you pip-installed the package to another version of python or in a virtualenvironment and you are trying to run the code to anothe one. I just run again the code and has no errors.

Comment: Where did you run `pip install` and where do you run your code? Give me a few info to help you.

Comment: I am running pip install in Anaconda prompt and i am running my code in 'anaconda spyder'.

Comment: I've never used anaconda, so I cannot give much help. Try to run also `conda install python-barcode` other than try to use another IDE or just a cmd to run it.

Comment: Which software are you using ? please share details. How can I use cmd for this?

Comment: you can run on cmd `pip install python-barcode`  to install the package on system's python and save the code to a file like 'test.py' then go to the location of that file from cmd and run 'python test.py'. I use PyCharm

Comment: Thank you for all the answers , now i get the solution for my problem . It's working properly.

Answer (score 1):

**Install treepoem package:**

```
pip install treepoem
# or
python -m pip install treepoem
```

**Run this code**

```
import treepoem
image = treepoem.generate_barcode(
    barcode_type="code128",  # One of the BWIPP supported codes.
    # barcode_type="qrcode",  
    # One of the BWIPP supported codes.
    # barcode_type="interleaved2of5",  # One of the BWIPP supported codes.
    # barcode_type="code128",  # One of the BWIPP supported codes.
    #    # barcode_type="isbn",  # One of the BWIPP supported codes.
    #    # data="978-3-16-148410-0",
    #   barcode_type="code128",  # One of the BWIPP supported codes.
    #   barcode_type="micropdf417",  # One of the BWIPP supported codes.
    #   barcode_type="ean13",  # One of the BWIPP supported codes.
    data="Your String -978316148fsd4100",
)
image.convert("1").save("output_qrcode_or_barcode.png")
```

[image]

[More Detalils](https://blog.jonasneubert.com/2019/01/23/barcode-generation-python/)

Comment: Great stuff.. Especially the article. Thank you! Needed a reliable and easy way to generate ITFs (interleaved2of5).

Answer (score 0):

```
import barcode
from barcode.writer import ImageWriter
from barcode import generate
def testEan():
    EAN = barcode.get_barcode_class('ean13')
    ean = EAN(u'5901234123457', writer=ImageWriter())
    fullname = ean.save('ean13_barcode')
    u'ean13_barcode.png'
    name = generate('EAN13', u'5901234123457', output='barcode_svg')
    print(name)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    testEan()
```

Answer (score 0):

install these packages:

pip install python-barcode

pip install Pillow

then try this code snippet:

```
from barcode import EAN13
from barcode.writer import ImageWriter

with open('sample.png', 'wb') as f:
    e = EAN13('123412341234', writer=ImageWriter())
    e.write(f)
```

Note:
EAN13 is one of the formats to generate, there are other formats available as well.
EAN13 expects 12 digits, and only numeric input is allowed.
The 12 digits is taken as input and the 13th digit is checksum of the input.

e.g:

input: 123412341234

output:1234123412344

Comment: Better answers have already been provided

Answer (score -1):

```
import barcode

hr = barcode.get_barcode_class('ean13')
Hr = hr('1234567891012')
qr = Hr.save('123')
```

Comment: It's basically the same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57427284/2745495).

Comment: Hello! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.