# Is it possbile to create a picture from a code 128 with reportlab?

Tags: python, image, reportlab, code128

Is it possible to create a png or jpng from a code 128 with reportlab?
This example Works with my DataMatrix-Generator. But with code 128 I get an error message.
something like this:

```
 from reportlab.graphics.barcode import code128
 from reportlab.lib.units import mm
 from reportlab.platypus import Image

 img_size = 12*mm
 encoder =code128.Code128("9831475934751'")
 encoder.save('path')
 img = Image('path', width=img_size, height=img_size)

 SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes 
 in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape.
```

My DataMatrix Generator:

```
def createDatamatrix(self):

  try:
      size = 12*mm
      data = data = 'SN: '+self.sn+'\nTN: '+self.tn+'\nConfigs: 
      '+self.config
      encoder = dme(data)
      encoder.save(self.sn+'.png')
      self.img = Image(self.sn+'.png', width=size, height=size)
    
except Exception:
    print("Error CreateDatamatrix")
```

Comment: perhaps see this example https://gist.github.com/luxinyan/11205358. It would also helpt if you specify what's not working with your current code.

Comment: @RobinDillen I copied the example from my Datamatrix-Generator. The save does not work. SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape. The Github example is to create a PDF.

Comment: a snippet from their website
    > ReportLab is the time-proven, ultra-robust open-source engine for creating complex, data-driven __PDF documents__

Comment: perhaps you just need to use another library like https://pypi.org/project/python-barcode/

Comment: @RobinDillen I already tried it with that library. But there I have a problem with the ghost script library, so I asked my question.

Comment: here is another library https://stackoverflow.com/a/69202223/10875953

Comment: I'm sorry that I found it not myself, thanks @RobinDillen